# How to convert an object that has an inner object into JSON

Tags: java, json

I am having an object as below

```
 public class Employee{
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String address;
  String phoneNumber;
  List<Contacts> Contacts;

}

 public class Contacts{
  String name;
  String Address;
  String phoneNumber;
}
```

Now considering the Employee object is set with values inside the application and when I try to convert the object say with name **empObject**(which has all values) into JSON as below

```
ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();
String employeeObjToJSON =mapper.writeValueAsString(empObject);
System.out.println("JSON employee Object" +employeeObjToJSON)
```

I get the values

```
{"firstName":"Sawyer","lastName":"Ford","phone":"4555454553", "address": "SNJFJJFJ", "contacts":[{"phoneNumber": "122333"},{"phoneNumber":"122222"}]}
```

Only the phone number is printed for the Inner Object. How should I get the complete object in JSON

Comment: Is it possible that the missing fields are `null`?

Comment: Rite they are null good catch!!!!...But even though I should get the complete format as it will let me know for which contacts the first name and lastname are null

Comment: You know they are null if they are not present. Null basically means that the data does not exist

Comment: I expect it should be like  `"contacts":[{"firstName": null, "lastName": null, phoneNumber": "122333"},]}` The reason is I like to catch them in logs and then I would come to know which phone numbers have firstName and lastName as Null

Answer (score 3):

Your class structure seems a little off. Why would the Employee class have a list of contacts as String, rather than a list of Contact objects?

I would suggest you change your Employee class like this:

```
public class Employee {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String address;
  String phoneNumber;
  List<Contact> contacts;
}

public class Contact {
  String name;
  String address;
  String phoneNumber;
}
```

Using this class structure you should not have any problems mapping them to JSON using ObjectMapper.

**Edit:** 
Regarding the null fields not being displayed, as I wrote in the comment, by default Jackson should serialise them and you should see them in the response.

If that is not the case, it might be that this serialisation feature has been overridden somewhere... try setting the following config to your object mapper and see if it works: `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`.

Alternatively, you can also use the Jackson annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` on your Employee class and Contact class like ibenjelloun suggested in his/her answer.

Comment: edited the question. Its my bad. But for null values the complete JSON is not formed.

Comment: @Sawyer look like you are missing some things, B. Thury solution must work
{"firstName":"f","lastName":"l","address":"q","phoneNumber":"c","contacts":[{"name":null,"phoneNumber":"p","address":null}]}

Comment: By default, null values should be serialised. Is it possible that you override this serialisation feature somewhere? Try setting the following config to your object mapper and see if it works:

`mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`

Comment: will try this after sometime and try to find whether it gets as required

Comment: @Sawyer: Strange. I just tried it and it works. Did you try with annotations or with `mapper.setSerializationInclusion()` ?

Comment: @BThuy: Sorry I didnt mention the employee class in the application is annotated with `@JSONInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` already. I tried `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(sonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)`  already but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following class annotation :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
```

According to the [javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html), it's the default value, maybe it is overwritten somewhere in your code ?